# Setting environment variables (TEXINPUTS) in El Capitan

Tags: macos, launchd, latex

I am a user of TeXShop, an application launched from the Launchpad. Everything works great except that in order to get full functionality, I need to set the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable. (To be precise, the variable must be set for certain processes launched by TexShop. It is normally inherited from the parent process.)

Until I upgraded to El Capitan, I could do this by calling `launchctl setenv TEXINPUTS some-appropriate-value`. Unfortunately, this has stopped working after upgrading. The command appears to succeed, and querying with `launchctl getenv TEXINPUTS` shows me the value I set, but it is not passed to applications I launch from the GUI. (I have confirmed this by launching a Terminal and checking the environment.)

The `launchctl` manual page has this to say about the `config system` command:

> `path`:     Sets the PATH environment variable for all services within the target domain to
>   the string value.  [...] Note that if a service specifies its
>   own PATH, the service-specific environment variable will take precedence.
>
> NOTE: This facility cannot be used to set general environment variables for all
>   services within the domain. It is intentionally scoped to the PATH environment
>   variable and nothing else for security reasons.

So it seems that Apple (a) does not want to pass my environment settings to applications willy-nilly, may have a way to customize the environment of specific "services". Does anyone know how I can get my editor to "see" the `TEXINPUTS` variable?

PS. Almost all related questions I've seen are about setting `PATH`. Solutions specific to setting the system path are not going to help here.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is well known and is due to Apple - the `/usr` folder cannot be anymore written. The solution is to add a link to this location: `/Library/TeX/texbin` - depending also on your TeX version, see more info in this link: https://tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue. They want an environment variable to be available to the program while running. That has nothing to do with a symbolic link pointing to the program's binaries.

Comment: Thanks but tubedogg is right. I have already resolved path issues. As I wrote, "everything works great", i.e., I can use latex and friends just fine.